# Android HttpURLConnection with HTTP Basic Authorization on RAILS Web Service

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, restkit, httpurlconnection

I'm trying around with the HttpURLConnection for quite some time now and I tried several solution posted here and on other places, but nothing seems to work.

I have the following architecture:

1. A Ruby on Rails Web Service (Rest interface with JSON)
2. An iPhone Client with RestKit
3. An Android Client with HttpURLConnection

The iPhone Client works like a charm. It connects to the web service with RestKit.

Now the Android Client is a completely different story. I always get a 401 Unauthorized message from the server (which results in a local FileNotFoundException).

The strange thing is, that the iPhone Client gets the same error, but RestKit somehow manages the handle it by sending the same request again. I tried that of course, but I just get the same error twice.

On the Rails Log Output it looks like this:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-03 12:44:56 +0200
Processing by Api::V1::ApiController#session_login as JSON
  Parameters: {"device"=>{"model"=>"Simulator", "system"=>"Android", "version"=>"Hugo", "name"=>"Android Simulator"}, "email"=>"florian.letz@simpliflow.com", "api"=>{"device"=>{"model"=>"Simulator", "system"=>"Android", "version"=>"Hugo", "name"=>"Android Simulator"}, "email"=>"florian.letz@simpliflow.com", "action"=>"session_login", "controller"=>"api/v1/api"}}
Filter chain halted as :require_login_from_http_basic rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The exact same message occurs when the iPhone Client connect's but then suddenly a magical second request occurs and it goes through.

On the Android Client I do the following:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod(HTTP_POST);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

String userpassword = email + ":" + password;
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userpassword.getBytes())));

String body = jsonLogin.toString();
byte[] body_bytes = body.getBytes();

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(body_bytes.length));
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
con.setUseCaches (false);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream ());
wr.write(body_bytes);
wr.flush ();
wr.close ();

InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
```

And on the last line the exception occurs.

I've read some things about redirects, but there is no redirect implemented at the server and I do not receive one on the client. I just get the 401 Unauthorized. The code in the web service and the iphone client indicate a quite simple workflow. Just send the data and receive the answer. I don't know where the SECOND login call comes from when the iPhone connects.

Does anyone here have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT #1:
I have identified the "magical" second request. The RestKit Log shows the following:

```
Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault
```

This then results in the second request with quite a buch of headers I cannot make any sense of.

So do you know a way to implement this in Android?

Comment: I've not actually solved the problem at hand with HttpURLConnection, but I've solved the overall problem by switching to a different library.

HttpClient from Apache can do all that's necessary.

But you cannot just put the apache jars in your project, you have to use the repackaged stuff from http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/ because the apache jars have conflicts with the old versions, that are included in android.